# Looking for SQL Query Assessment Test for Interview Purposes

Tags: sql, testing

I'm looking for a good service that provides SQL Query Assessment tests that I can use for interview purposes.

Right now we have a third party that manages our database so I am strictly interested in testing that targets querying ability. Position would be for an analyst that only needs to have query specific knowledge.

I'm having a hard time finding something that only focuses on this specific area. Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: could you not just give the candidate read access to the database and a specification for the results that you want, then see how they get on?

Comment: Can you just create your own internal asseessment for that specific area you are intrested in and see how the candidate gets on.

Comment: I cant provide access to our actual data. There is sensitive data that I do not want to provide to a non-employee and most of the data relationships are industry specific which would put non-industry applicants at a disadvantage (industry experience is not a requirement).

Comment: I found testdome.com which seems to be close... but not perfect. I'm okay paying for a solution, just need one that provides query questions and scoring.